# How to get Ram, Cpu & Time Utilization of a python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu-usage

I want to know Ram, Cpu & Time Utilization of my python program. I have used psutil, but it gives me the overall utilization of my CPU.
I want to know the specific usage of my CPU, RAM and also how much time required to execute it.
I want to do this in Google Colab. I already search n number of posts, but nothing works for me.

Thanks